# Next.JS - Data Persistence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to fetch data at app load/user login and then persist that data through the application? Every page refresh clears context and when we try to request via getServerSideProps the data is undefined and crashes the app since the page tries to load/generate before the data request has resolved.

Comment: Are you following the instructions of this link? https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication#authenticating-server-rendered-pages

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux and safe the data in you localstorage.